# What is the correct publication date for Thucydides' The Peloponnesian War?

Tags: ancient-greece, historiography, greek

At [Archive.org: Thucydides - The Peloponnesian War](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.461316) I found a digital edition of the subject work as translated by Rex Warner (9 March 1905 – 24 June 1986) with a purported publication date of 1916.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Peloponnesian_War) lists original publication date of 1954.

So I'm having trouble with the apparent contradiction. And if initially published in 1916 as the book claims, then Rex would've apparently been age 11 years or so when he finished the first translation, which seems unlikely.

I tried accessing the book source via link on archive.org (Book Source: Digital Library of India Item 2015.461316) but it is unavailable for me just prior to posting this question.

I noticed that the title of the archive.org edition (The Peloponnesian War) differs slightly from the title as listed in Wikipedia (History of the Peloponnesian War) but that seems of little significance to me.

So my question: is the digital edition publication date of 1916 correct or is Wikipedia's initial publication date of 1954 correct? Or other?

Comment: Its it possible that's the original publication date, at which point someone else had done the translation? If its not something like that, you're probably going to have to ask the person who filled out that bit on the form at Archive.org, as that's the only place we know that date appears. For all we know, it could just be a data entry error.

Comment: Warner's introduction notes that Crawley's version was published in 1876 and goes on to say that it was "nearly eighty [years] since the publication of Crawley's version". That would suggest that Warner wrote his introduction in the 1950s, which matches with a 1954 publication date. The 1916 publication date is mentioned only once in the book (and there is no other copyright or publication information) so it could well be a typo.

Comment: @T.E.D. The Archive.org info is probably taken from the publication date given in the [book](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.461316/page/n3/mode/1up) which says "First published 1916".

Comment: @SteveBird, wow! Now the situation is hard to understand! :)

Comment: Just to add extra confusion, the [publication page](https://archive.org/details/historyofpelopo000thuc/page/n5/mode/1up) for a later paperback version states that "This translation first published 1954" and lists reprints from 1956 up to 1971. It then says "Revised, with a new introduction and appendices, 1952"! However, the copyright section states that the new "Introduction and Appendices copyright (c) M. I. Finley 1972" which suggests that the 1952 revision date is a typo too. Overall, the people responsible for publication data in Penguin books seem to be a little slack.

Comment: Revised the title; clear questions in the title seem to generate better answers.

Comment: Page 304 of the 2016 [Penguin Annotated Catalog](http://www.penguin.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/PenguinAnnotatedCatalog2016.pdf) officially confirms the actual translation, not just its signed preface, to have been Warner's. [Cyril Edward Robinson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyril_E._Robinson)'s 1916 first edition of [The Days of Alkibiades](http://archive.org/search.php?query=alkibiades+robinson), a major player in the aforementioned war, available on the same site in three versions, two of which are from the same Indian National Library, might have been the source of the confusion.